# Mageto2 and PWA - How to setup the PWA in exiting Magento Docker?

Tags: docker, magento2, progressive-web-apps

I have already setup the Magento 2.4.3-P1 project in docker. Now I wants to setup the PWA in same. Please can someone suggest that how I can achieve this?